# Filtering FEC data by duplicates and cross-referencing across multiple datasets with R

Tags: r, aggregate, data-science

I am looking at FEC data for two political candidate. FEC data is organized by individual donation, rather than by donor. So if someone donates to a candidate 3 times, their name will appear 3 times.

How do I use R to get rid of duplicate names and create a column with their total donation? Then, how can I see which donors who have donated to one candidate have also donated to the second one?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a minimally reproducible example, by using `dput(head(df))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by grouping by donor id. Here is an example using the built in iris data, as you dont provide an example of your data you would need to modify this to use your dataframe and variable names:

```
# SETUP
library(data.table)
# convert built in data iris to a data.table
dtIris <- data.table(iris)
# view data so you can see that dataset 
dtIris

# SOLUTIONS 
# sum petal.length by species
dtIris[, sum(Petal.Length), by = "Species"]
# or sum each variable by species
dtIris[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "Species"]
# sum petal.length by species and add to original dataset
dtIris[, sumPL := sum(Petal.Length), by = "Species"]
```

I'm going to assume you have each candidate in different datasets, it sounds like it to me, but you need to give more detail and a reproducible example. This is done by reducing the first dataset, then chaining a second expression to join the second (reduced) dataset and specifying `on` and `nomatch`

```
# SETUP
# create two datasets, one per candidate for the example
dt1 <- data.table(
  donor = c("a", "a", "b"), 
  amount = c(1365, 2976, 6164))
dt2 <- data.table(
  donor = c("b", "b", "c"), 
  amount = c(662, 793, 1504))
# SOLUTION 
# sum by id, and join to return details for those that donate to both 
dt1[, sum(amount), by = "donor"][
  dt2[, sum(amount), by = "donor"], on = "donor", nomatch = 0]
```